# How to put a target result in a different location than the target name when generating target from pattern without rebuilding from unchanged sources?

Tags: makefile

I have a project structure that looks something like this:

```
.
├── Makefile
└── src/
    ├── a.c
    └── b.c
```

Each file in `src/` is a standalone program and I want to be able to compile individually by calling `make [program name]`, where `[program name]` corresponds to the filename without extension, i.e. `make a` should compile `a` from `src/a.c`. However, I want the compiled programs to be put in a separate directory, `bin/`, so the structure after calling `make a` should be:

```
.
├── bin/
│   └── a
├── Makefile
└── src/
    ├── a.c
    └── b.c
```

What I have so far is this rule:

```
% : src/%.c
        -mkdir -p bin/
        $(CC) $< -o bin/$@
```

This has the unfortunate side-effect of always rebuilding, even if the source files haven't changed. There is quite a large number of files in `src/` so specific rules for each file is undesirable. My question is this, then: Is it possible to have a make target that puts the result in a different location than the target name without rebuilding when sources haven't changed, and without having to create specific targets for each file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your rule *must* use the target that is actually built, else make will always rebuild it.  You must write your target like this:

```
bin/% : src/%.c
        -mkdir -p $(@D)
        $(CC) $< -o $@
```

Now, if you want to create an "alias" for the targets so you don't have to write the full pathname on the command line you can do something like this:

```
% : bin/% ;
```

(note the semicolon: you have to provide a recipe with a pattern rule even if it's empty).

If course you can always use `$(wildcard src/*.c)` to get a list of all the source files and create rule to build everything based on that, and use this to create aliases as well:

```
SRCS := $(wildcard src/*.c)

all: $(SRCS:src/%.c=bin/%)

$(SRC:src/%.c=%) : % : bin/% ;
```

This requires GNU make, but pattern rules are GNU make anyway.

Comment: Thanks, the "alias" is exactly what I was looking for! Just out of curiosity though, is there a simple way to do this that's portable?

Comment: No.  There is no portable way to write a makefile that works with targets in other directories, except by writing out all the rules explicitly (pattern rules are not part of the POSIX standard and their alternative, suffix rules, cannot support the target and prerequisite in different directories).  And there's no way to "get a list of files" in POSIX standard make.